# Linear programming - Know if a variable is even

Tags: linear-programming

how can i do this with linear programming? I've been thinking it for a while and i can't get it :/ neither can find it solved here.

I have two variables, X (integer) and Y (binary).

I want to store 1 in Y if X is even, 0 if it's not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constraint

```
y = 1 iff X is even
```

can be modeled using an extra integer variable z:

```
x = 2 z + (1-y)
z integer
```